# Copy file to xclip and paste to Firefox

Tags: x11, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm coping file to `xclip`

`cat file.txt | xclip`

I'm pasting without problem with

`xclip -o`

When I want to paste it to `Firefox` with `Ctrl+V` it pastes old text (that shouldn't already be in the clipboard).

When I go back to terminal and run `xclip -o` it pastes the correct text.

Why is there a problem with pasting to `Firefox`?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

X11 has several available clipboards. By default, `xclip` places data in the primary selection buffer. To paste it, you use middle-click.

If you want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, use `xclip -selection clipboard`. See `man xclip` for more information.

There is good information about the different clipboards on [freedesktop.org](http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt).

Comment: On a side note: I just noticed that xclip's option `-f, -filter` is a built in `tee` . It writes to the clipboard and to stdout at the same time. That could come in handy (for something).

Comment: It can be useful to add the file's mimetype: `-t $(file -b --mime-type "$1")`

Comment: `xclip -selection clipboard` can be shortened to `xclip -se c`.

Answer (score 55):

Copy to your clipboard with:

```
xclip -sel clip < ~/path/to/file.txt
```

and then paste <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> wherever you wish to.

Comment: Note that the shorthand `xclip -se c < myfile` would also do, since xclip admits abbreviations provided they don't conflict with valid options and keywords (`-silent` and `-selection`, for example)

Answer (score 5):

Add this to to your `~/.bashrc`

```
# now `cclip' can be used when you it to be available to `ctrl-[vxc]'
alias cclip='xclip -selection clipboard'
```

alternatively, run this:

```
echo 'alias cclip='"'"'xclip -selection clipboard'"'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
$ cat file.txt | xclip -i
```

`xclip` will read from stdin with option `-i`. If you want to copy to clipboard, run command:

```bsh
$ xclip -o | xclip -sel clip
```