# Copy image from command-line to clipboard

Tags: bash, command-line, images, clipboard

Is there a way in a bash to copy a picture to the clipboard?

For example if there is a picture `mypic.png` I want to have a command like `clipcopy mypic.png` such that I can go for example to inkscape and paste it afterwards.

Comment: This should be broken in two steps: 1. what data does Inkscape expect to be on the clipboard? E.g. file content or file path. I imagine content since path is trivial with `xsel -b`? 2. How to get that data on the clipboard.

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/301851/how-to-copy-a-picture-to-clipboard-from-command-line-in-linux

Comment: More general question for any file type: http://superuser.com/questions/796376/is-is-possible-to-copy-binary-data-containing-a-nul-character-to-the-x-clipboard

Comment: If you have ImageMagick installed, I believe the command is `convert ... clipboard:` (... are the other arguments including your filename).

Answer (score 12):

You can use [CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) for this. From the website:

> Clipboard manager with advanced features
>
> - CopyQ is clipboard manager with searchable and editable history.
> - Supports Linux and Windows.
> - Experimental support for OS X 10.9+.
> - Store text, HTML, images and any other custom format.
> - Advanced command-line interface and scripting.

To copy an image (you need to indicate the MIME type):

```
copyq write image/png - < file.png && copyq select 0
```

To copy a data file (you need to indicate the MIME type):

```
copyq write application/pdf - < file.pdf && copyq select 0
```

Check their wiki for more [documentation and usage examples](http://sourceforge.net/p/copyq/wiki/Home/).

See also:

- [A command-line clipboard copy and paste utility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility/443738#443738)

Comment: Your first option using png works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

See the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/759660/187689

`xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i example.png`

Answer (score 9):

[This python script](https://superuser.com/questions/199285/how-to-copy-image-to-clipboard-to-paste-to-another-application/247069#247069) by [cheshirekow](https://superuser.com/users/17824/cheshirekow) claims to do what you want.

```python
#! /usr/bin/python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import os
import sys

def copy_image(f):
    assert os.path.exists(f), "file does not exist"
    image = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(f)

    clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
    clipboard.set_image(image)
    clipboard.store()

copy_image(sys.argv[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works to past into libreoffice, however pasting into inkscape doesn't.

Comment: Nice one, it works well with pasting into xournal.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a short bash script that uses `xclip` to copy a file.

You should be able to paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

```
#!/bin/bash
command -v xclip >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "Need command xclip. Aborting." >&2; exit 1; }
[[ -f "$1" ]] || { echo "Error: Not a file." >&2; exit 1; }
TYPE=$(file -b --mime-type "$1")
xclip -selection clipboard -t "$TYPE" < "$1"
```

Thanks to...

- [Copy file to xclip and paste to Firefox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22494/copy-file-to-xclip-and-paste-to-firefox)
- [Copy image from clipboard to file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145131/copy-image-from-clipboard-to-file)
- [How can I check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: This copies into office fine, but not into xournal!

Answer (score 5):

I've edited [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78255/65525) to allow pipe input:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

def store(pixbuf):
        clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
        clipboard.set_image(pixbuf)
        clipboard.store()

def copy_image(f):
    image = Gtk.Image.new_from_file(f)
    if image.get_storage_type() == Gtk.ImageType.PIXBUF:
        pixbuf = image.get_pixbuf()
        store(pixbuf)
    else:
        print("Copying failed")

def copy_pixbuf(data):
    loader = GdkPixbuf.PixbufLoader()
    loader.write(data)
    loader.close()
    pixbuf = loader.get_pixbuf()
    store(pixbuf)

if sys.stdin.isatty():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: image-to-clipboard.py image")
    else:
        f = sys.argv[1]
        copy_image(f);
else:
    data = sys.stdin.read()
    copy_pixbuf(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `xclip` only works for X11.

A solution for Wayland:

```
wl-copy -t image/png < myimage.png
```