# Copy image from clipboard to file

Tags: scripting, x11, images, clipboard

Is it possible to take an image from the clipboard and output it to a file (using X)?

I can do this with text easily:

```
$ xclip -selection c -o > file.text
```

But when I try the above with an image nothing is written.

---

The reason I want to do this is I don't have an image editor installed, and it got me thinking whether I could do this without installing one.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can actually do this with `xclip` using `-t` option.

1. See what targets are available:

> ```
> $ xclip -selection clipboard -t TARGETS -o
> TARGETS
> image/png
> text/html
> ```

2. Note the `image/png` target; go ahead and get it:

> ```
> $ xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o > /tmp/clipboard.png
> ```

Refer to the [ICCCM Section 2.6.2](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2.6.2) for further reading.

**Note:** xclip SVN revision 81 (from April 2010) or [patches](http://sourceforge.net/p/xclip/patches/4/) later required.

Comment: I am using 0.12, the one that is offered by `pacman` so I shall have to get the upstream version. Thanks!

Comment: Error: target image/png not available
this be old. Debian stretch

Comment: @Stígandr I confirmed this still works on my machine running Debian testing (stretch). Maybe you copied a JPEG or some other type of image? Probably best to ask a new question rather than debug it in comments.

Comment: On my machine, i needed to specify `-selection primary` instead.

Comment: @phil294 that's the other X clipboard, the two used ones are primary and clipboard (there are others, but nothing uses them). Primary is normally select and middle-click, clipboard is normally copy/paste

Comment: Can I test the results of target? i.e is my image type available

Comment: @zzapper it spits out the types available, so you can test it by piping to `grep` for example.

Answer (score 3):

xclip doesn't work with images on my computer (svn84-4) :

```
$ xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o
Error: target image/png not available
```

But there is another program which take screenshot and paste it into a file, very simply : [scrot](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-take-screenshots-in-linux-with-scrot) :

```
scrot /tmp/myImage.png
```

Comment: It appears 'scrot' takes screenshot of my GNOME Terminal instead of taking it from clipboard. 'man' pages appears to be indicating no flag for this