# Pasting the content of xclip onto gedit

Tags: x11, clipboard, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy file to xclip and paste to Firefox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22494/copy-file-to-xclip-and-paste-to-firefox)

I would use the following command to copy the output of `uptime` to the clipboard:

```
uptime | xclip
```

Then I can paste the copied uptime to the console by clicking the middle button of mouse. But when I go to an application like "gedit", there is no *Paste* option available there. How can I copy a text into clipboard so that it could be pasted onto something like "gedit"?

Comment: Does middle click not work in gedit?

Comment: @jw013 No it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar issue until I did the following (on Ubuntu):

> uptime | xclip -selection c

From the man pages:

```
-selection
             specify  which X selection to use, options are "primary" to
             use XA_PRIMARY (default), "secondary" for  XA_SECONDARY  or
             "clipboard" for XA_CLIPBOARD
```

Comment: Note that the shorthand `uptime | xclip -se c` would also do, since xclip admits abbreviations provided they don't conflict with valid options and keywords (`-silent` and `-selection`, for example)