# VIM map not working

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm trying to map `<c-y>,` (from zencoding-vim) to `<c-m>`.

I tried:

```
map <C-m> <C-y>,
map <C-m> <C-y>,<cr>
```

But doesn't seems to be working. Maybe it's something with the comma?

Comment: Possible in Xterm: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the comma, it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> which is the terminal control sequence for
return and the same as pressing the return key. Try typing `ls` in your
terminal and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>. You'll run into the same problem trying to map
<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>, which is the terminal control sequence for backspace.

This is not a Vim issue since Vim can't distinguish between <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>`and`
return` key presses.

Comment: Tried mapping to <C-q> and <C-y> and still the same problem. Maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: <C-q> is usually the terminal control sequence for unstop output. <C-s> is to stop output.

Comment: @jviotti Try to use the specified mappings `imap` for insert mode mapping `nmap` for normal mode mapping, etc. I don't use zencoding and it works here with other mappings.