# xclip copy file so it can be pasted as a file (not file content)

Tags: file-copy, clipboard, xclip

How can I copy a file with xclip, so that it is pastable as a file in file explorers?

I searched on google an so on and found stuff like this [Copy file to xclip and paste to Firefox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22494/255155), but there it is always about the content of files. What I need is being able to copy a file with an xclip command so that I will be able to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> in the file explorer.

I am using deepin 15.8 beta and if I copy a file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> I get this one in the TARGETS, which seems like an indicator somehow: `x-special/gnome-copied-files`

But eg. when I copy a file with this, I am not able to paste it in the file manager:

```
xclip -selection c -i -t x-special/gnome-copied-files test.txt
```